# How to permanently gain full access to a Huawei EchoLife HG8245Q2 router?

Tags: router

I want full access to an [Huawei EchoLife HG8245Q2](https://e.huawei.com/us/products/fixed-network/access/ont/echolife-hg8245q2) router ([documentation](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/access-network/echolife-hg8245q2-pid-21989531)). I disconnected the router from the Internet, factory reset it which worked with username `telecomadmin` and password `admintelecom`. However, it's not permanent and the access gets removed. I tried to modify standard user UserLevel to 0, but it gets removed when connected.

Comment: Do you own the router or does your ISP? Are you renting/leasing the router from them or did you buy it from the store? Even if you own the router, your ISP may require full control of the router and may not allow you to have the access you want.

Comment: Do you mean im not allowed to change settings of my router? I came here to get help.

Comment: _arkadiusz1234_, yes, you bought it. However, if the ISP finds a change of settings it considers a critical problem, they can fail to provide Internet access.

Comment: No, you came here to get answers, which is an important distinction. The answer to your question relies on the methods and policies of your ISP. For instance, I went to the store and purchased a modem compatible with my ISP, set up the local admin account, and adjusted the settings to my liking, and when I connected the modem to the lines to get service, the ISP took over my modem and my configurations no longer apply, even though I entirely own my modem. This is be design, and I may not like it, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 2):

This depends entirely on the policies and methods of the ISP. If the ISP requires control of the device in order to offer their service, the device WILL give itself up to the ISPs control.

This is how some internet connection methods and ISPs work, and the only say in the matter is whether you choose to continue with that ISP or go to another which may have policies more to your liking.

What you CAN do is call your ISP and ask whether they require this sort of control, and whether or not you can have some access to your router's configuration. They may take control by default, but may not actually require this control, if you're lucky.